# Webdriver cannot work well on clicking 'Start Date icon' and 'End Date icon'

Tags: python, webdriver

I'm using Webdriver-Python to write automation click on 'Start Date' icon, 'End Date' icon to fill the date into these fields.

Here the Date field in my web:

```
|Period:|_____(1)_____[Start Date icon]|_____(2)_____[End Date icon]
```

(1),(2) are the text fields, we can enter the date directly instead of clicking Date icon.

Clicking StartDate/EndDate icon, a pop-up Calendar window (title in HTML code is Calendar) will display, after choose a date, this will be written to (1)/(2) and pop-up disappear.

In my code, I will click Start Date, then chose a date, then click the 'End Date' icon. But Webdriver cannot find the location of 'End Date' icon. Try to click 'End Date' icon first, then to Start Date, it cannot find 'Start Date' icon location

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://local/time")
assert "ABM - Activity Reference" in driver.title

start_Date= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='startDate']/img")
start_Date.click()
driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
start_date_Choose = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/a")
start_date_Choose.click()

time.sleep(5)

end_Date= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='endDate']/img")
end_Date.click()
```

Here is the console log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Eclipse_workspace\Robot\src\Excel\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    end_Date= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='endDateTxt2']/img")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 223, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 655, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.41.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: u'no such window: target window already closed\nfrom unknown error: web view not found\n  (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.114)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.0 SP2 x86)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the window is switched and date is selected,u need to select the old window back.
That can be done by saving old window before switching.

```
current=window.handles[0]
```

After selecting date:

```
driver.switch_to_window(current)
```